# Error 403 Forbidden - Account Disabled When Publishing NPM Package

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I'm trying to publish a new npm package called nibble-qmk-hid. I've created the project via `npm init`. I've logged into npm via `npm login`, and then when I try to publish the package via `npm publish --access public`, I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - PUT https://npm.pkg.github.com/@ajcav2/nibble-qmk-hid - The "ajcav2" account is disabled and can't accept package uploads.
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.
```

How is it that my account is disabled? How to I enable my account?

Comment: Hi! Could you share the contents of `package.json`?